# Time picker above 24 hours in React

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, antd, timepicker

I am using ant design `TimePicker` component in my react project. It naturally shows 24 hours and its range is between `0:0:0` and `23:59:59`. I need to 72 hours version of it limited `71:59:59`. So is it possible to make this happen with a library (ant design or another UI design language) or should I write a custom `TimePicker` for this challenge. Thank you in advance.